# STM32F103RB - How to know what pin to use to send a trigger signal

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, nucleo

First of all forgive me as I am a beginner in embedded systems.

I am using a Nucleo STM32F103RB. I am trying to send a trigger signal from my STM to a FPGA card, by setting a GPIO pin of my STM but I am unsure about which pin to connect.

This is the code I use to drive my GPIO:

```
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(Trigger_GPIO_Port, Trigger_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
//do something
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(Trigger_GPIO_Port, Trigger_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
```

with `Trigger_GPIO_Port` and `Trigger_Pin` being defined as follows:

```
#define Trigger_Pin GPIO_PIN_2
#define Trigger_GPIO_Port GPIOB
```

By using STMCube32 software I had the following picture:

[image]

So, I connected the PC9 pin of my board as the trigger by basing myself off the picture STM32Cube gave me.

Am I wrong in doing that? This doesn't seem to work...
How can I simply send a trigger from my board?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Personally I'd avoid CubeMX.  I can see how for  a beginner it seems attractive over bare-metal or the older Standard Peripheral Library, but if you want that kind of easy-in, I'd suggest using Mbed (https://os.mbed.com/).  It is fully supported on [your board](https://os.mbed.com/platforms/ST-Nucleo-F103RB/), and is ARM microcontroller rather than STM32 specific, so you have a wider choice of platforms and boards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CubeMX pinout suggests PC9, but your code:

```
#define Trigger_Pin GPIO_PIN_2
#define Trigger_GPIO_Port GPIOB
```

clearly defines PB2 as in GPIO **P**ort **B** pin **2**.

It looks like at some stage you have modified the CubeMX configuration but failed to re-generate the code.  You should have:

```
#define Trigger_Pin GPIO_PIN_9
#define Trigger_GPIO_Port GPIOC
```

Or simply connect PB2 - although if you want to keep your code and CubeMX in sync, I suggest you regenerate the code, especially if you have made other changes that also need to be included.

In the Nucleo connector pin-out, the labels in blue correspond to the microcontroller pins. The magenta labels are the corresponding Arduino Shield pin names.